# Programmatic configuration of NLog in ASP.NET Core application to filter unwanted chatter?

Tags: asp.net-core, nlog

I'm attempting to filter out all the unnecessary chatter from the Microsoft hosting assemblies, while still allowing Debug-level messages from our own code to pass through to our logging targets.

Here's code that configures NLog and initializes a web app.  Unfortunately, the Microsoft.* and System.* namespace filtering does not functional at all.  The result is that all messages Debug and higher are logged.

I do not want to use the old nlog.config process.  I want to be able to build the LoggingConfiguration in code.

I really must be missing something easy here, but I don't see it!

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // Read configuration from a variety of sources to compose our final IConfiguration
    var config = ReadOurConfigFromLotsOfPlaces();

    var nLogConfig = new LoggingConfiguration();
    var consoleTarget = new ColoredConsoleTarget("console")
    {
        AutoFlush = true,
        ErrorStream = true,
        Layout = @"${date:format=yyyy-MM-dd HH\:mm\:ss.fff} ${level} [${logger}] - ${message}${onexception:${newline}}${exception:format=shortType,message,stackTrace:maxInnerExceptionLevel=5}"
    };
    nLogConfig.AddTarget(consoleTarget);
    nLogConfig.LoggingRules.Add(new LoggingRule("Microsoft.*", LogLevel.Warn, consoleTarget) {Final = true});
    nLogConfig.LoggingRules.Add(new LoggingRule("System.*", LogLevel.Warn, consoleTarget) {Final = true});
    nLogConfig.LoggingRules.Add(new LoggingRule("*", LogLevel.Debug, consoleTarget));
            
    var logger = NLogBuilder.ConfigureNLog(nLogConfig).GetCurrentClassLogger();
    logger.Debug("NLog initialization complete");
    try
    {
        logger.Debug("init main");
        CreateHostBuilder(config).Build().Run();
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        logger.Error(exception, "Stopped program because of exception");
        throw;
    }
    finally
    {
        // Ensure to flush and stop internal timers/threads before application-exit (Avoid segmentation fault on Linux)
        LogManager.Shutdown();
    }
}

public static IWebHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(IConfiguration config)
{
    // we don't call CreateDefaultBuilder() because we already have assembled the configuration we want to use
    return new WebHostBuilder()
        .UseConfiguration(config)
        .UseKestrel(options => options.UseSystemd())
        .UseStartup<Startup>()
        .ConfigureLogging(logging =>
        {
            logging.ClearProviders();
            logging.SetMinimumLevel(Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.LogLevel.Trace);
        })
        .UseNLog();
}
```

Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Ugh.  I understand my problem now:  The 'LoggingRules' is looking for a positive match between logger name and the min/max level values, so my first two LoggingRule objects did not match messages coming from the Microsoft.* and System.* namespaces, so the rules did nothing with those messages.

In order to accomplish the filtering I want, this is the solution:

```
var nLogConfig = new LoggingConfiguration();
var consoleTarget = new ColoredConsoleTarget("console")
{
    AutoFlush = true,
    ErrorStream = true,
    Layout = @"${date:format=yyyy-MM-dd HH\:mm\:ss.fff} ${level} [${logger}] - ${message}${onexception:${newline}}${exception:format=shortType,message,stackTrace:maxInnerExceptionLevel=5}"
};
nLogConfig.AddTarget(consoleTarget);
var nullTarget = new NullTarget("null");
nLogConfig.AddTarget(nullTarget);
// matches every Microsoft.* logger with a LogLevel less than LogLevel.Warn
nLogConfig.LoggingRules.Add(new LoggingRule("Microsoft.*", LogLevel.Trace, LogLevel.Info, nullTarget) {Final = true});
// matches every System.* logger with a LogLevel less than LogLevel.Warn
nLogConfig.LoggingRules.Add(new LoggingRule("System.*", LogLevel.Trace, LogLevel.Info, nullTarget) {Final = true});
// and everything else, LogLevel.Debug and higher
nLogConfig.LoggingRules.Add(new LoggingRule("*", LogLevel.Debug, consoleTarget));
```